# How to block website from webbrowser?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to block websites in visual basic before the website actually loads?

For example, if I try to load [www.google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk) and hit go it doesn't load the website but give an error message. I have tried searching but cannot find what I am looking for.

Comment: You should add the error message you get `in text` here. It might help others to understand what exactly failed.

Answer (score 1):

Use Navigating EventArgs.

Example:

```
Private Sub wbMain_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles wbMain.Navigating
        If e.Url.ToString = "https://www.google.co.uk" Then
            MsgBox("Not allowed")
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Worked:

```
  '
  '
Dim MyURL As String
  '
  '  
Private Sub Command1_Click()
 MyURL = "http://www.website.com"
 WebBrowser1.Navigate2 MyURL
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, Flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
 If Instr(URL, MyURL) > 0 Then
   Cancel = True ' Do not allow
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How does this stop an actual web browser from visiting the site?  Does this only work when using a custom web browser application that you wrote?